# Using multiple datasets in RDLC

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc

I am working on rdlc reports, and the reports work just fine. I got stuck when I added one more dataset to the rdlc file. On adding the dataset, it added a data source as well. I ran the project, and the report was no more working giving the error: ***A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source***
Can some one please guide me on what steps to take in order to use multiple datasets. I am using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: you have to give add both datset names

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error While Using Multiple Datasets in RDLC Report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936389/error-while-using-multiple-datasets-in-rdlc-report)

Comment: nah, i believe its not a duplicate. As Amol (the asker of the question you referred) faced problem when he tried to access the data. I haven't yet tried to access the data. Just adding a dataset caused problem for me.

Answer (score 9):

**Multiple Datasources are added as follows:**

```
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rdS);
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rdS1);
```

**Refer this link:**

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/robo60/StandaloneRDLCReports11142007183516PM/StandaloneRDLCReports.aspx

All the parts are covered in this.

**Also refer this usefull discussion:**

http://forums.asp.net/t/1241964.aspx

Comment: I even tried this as well, but was getting the same error. Still I'll have a look at the link you provided. Hope it works for me.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: yeah these links has all the photos and explained stepwise. second link has quality discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this--

```
ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add("DataSet_Name",DataTable);
ReportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Important note-- the dataset name has to match the name that appears in the rdlc.  To make sure you know what this is, open the rdlc in XML Editor and find out what the name of the dataset is.  When you add the datasource programatically you must reference this name as it appears in the rdlc exactly.