# How to display two sets of data in a tablix

Tags: reporting-services

at the moment I have two tables. I have one table that displays loan summaries.

```
Loan    Client     Balance
 11       Bob       100000
 20       Steven    100000
 33       Michael   100000
```

I need to enhance this table by adding Loan.Notes

```
Loan    Client     Balance
 11       Bob       50000
 2015-05-06 - Bob came into the office and said we should expect late payments
 20       Steven    100000
 2015-05-06 - Steven came into the office and he will pay this friday
 2015-05-06 - Steven came into the office and said we should expect late payments
 33       Michael   700000
```

The Notes section has two columns, Date of note and the Note.Subject. May I ask how do I add in the notes section onto the tablix?

Comment: Some of this may depend on your reporting services/SSRS version. What version are you working with?

Comment: how do you know which note is related to which loan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create the query joining `Loan` with the 'LoanNotes'.

In your main table group by `Loan`. In the header of that group show `Loan #, client and balance`.

[image]

In the Detail section based on your requirements merge the column and show the `Notes` Data. In the following case I merged three columns and created a expression as `=Fields!NoteDate.Value & " - " & Fields!Subject.Value`

[image]

Now when you run the report you will get the data as you want.

[image]

**Optional:** In the case where there is no note you will need to write an expression in visibility tab to hide your detail row

```
=IIF(CountRows("LoanGroup") = 1, True, False)
```

OR

```
=CountRows("LoanGroup") = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for this is to combine the tables into one datatable joining on a similar key.

You can join the tables in your dbms by using queries to create a new view. or you could use this [`DataSet JOIN Helper`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/326080).
You can then group in your Tablix as you see fit.

Another solution would be to add multiple DataSets within the same report.
[Using multiple datasets in RDLC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826772/using-multiple-datasets-in-rdlc)