# What options am I left with SSRS for given scenario

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a database relationship as follow,

```
MasterEmployee
   EmployeeName
   ...Other Employee Details
   EmployeeAddress
       HistoryOfAddresses (dataset)
   EmployeePositions
       CurrentAndHistoryOfPositions (another dataset)
   .... other datasets
```

I need to create a SSRS report for above, I think best way is to create a master worksheet and then add a worksheet for each of child dataset.

To achieve above I have a SQL query that returns me below,

```
<Employees>
      <Employee>
          <ID>185</ID>
          <Name>18_108669635</Name>
          ... Other attributes

          <Addresses>
              <Address>
                  <ID>1</ID>
                  <Location>79 Baker Street</Location>
                  <CurrentAddress>false</CurrentAddress>
              </Address>
              .. Other addresses
          </Addresses>
          <Other datasets like positions in company etc..>
      </Employee>
</Employees>
```

Now I am not able to figure out how can I use this dataset above to show it in a ssrs report and how ?

Comment: What exactly are you asking...do you want to know how to display it visually? how to actually get the data on the report? How to get the datasets set up correctly to get on the report? And even these questions are probably too broad.. The only advice I can give you already is that you  should join the datasets (tables) together before you pass them to the reporter. So just create a new dataset from a view that joins your tables so you have all the data you want to show in a single dataset. Then on the report you can use grouping to get the desired structure.

Comment: @Oceans I am able to do what I wanted to do and posted it as a answer, I hope it clears your questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sort a figured out what I need to do to achieve my goals,

1) Add several datasets to a report, then create a new table for each dataset

2) Add page name and page break in start for each table in tablix properties that I want to display as a different sheet in excel.

3) Save this rdl file, then use code behind to add several data sets as explained in this post,

[Using multiple datasets in RDLC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826772/using-multiple-datasets-in-rdlc)

4) Render report and export it as excel in code behind.

I hope it will help others doing something similar.

5) I still need to add Vlookups in master sheet but that's another story.