# Error while getting multiple Datasets in RDLC report

Tags: c#, reporting-services, report, rdlc

I have a RDLC report with two datasets and it gives 'The definition of the report C:\Employee.rdlc' is invalid error whenever it runs. The report works fine if i only use one dataset.

**Here is the setup:**
For the report, i have added one datasource (i.e. Dataset) (name: 'dtsrcEmployee'' and used 'TableAdapter' to add two existing stored procedures from the existing database.  In the report, i have added this **dataset as DataSource**. Also in report, i have added **two dataset** (name: dtGetEmployeeSummary, dtGetEmployeeStats) which points to **two datatable** from the **datasource**.

From the code side, i am passing **dataset** which has **two datatable(datatable names matches with each dataset name in the Report)** (i.e dtGetEmployeeSummary, dtGetEmployeeStats). Also i am using 'First' tag in report fields as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936389/error-while-using-multiple-datasets-in-rdlc-report)

```
ReportViewer reportViewer = new ReportViewer();
reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
reportViewer.SizeToReportContent = true;
reportViewer.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
reportViewer.Height = Unit.Percentage(100);
reportViewer.ShowZoomControl = false;
reportViewer.ShowRefreshButton = false;
reportViewer.ShowBackButton = false;
reportViewer.ShowFindControls = false;

reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = reportPath;

foreach (DataTable reportTable in reportDataSet.Tables)
{
    reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(reportTable.TableName, reportTable));
}

var resportParameterLists = new List<ReportParameter>();
foreach (var keyValuePair in parameters)
{
    resportParameterLists.Add(new ReportParameter(keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value));
}
reportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(resportParameterLists);

reportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();

return reportViewer;
```

Any idea why i am getting error while using second dataset but not while using only one?

Thanks

> Update: I ended up deleting the report and created new one with two
>   datasets and Yes it worked this time. Not sure what was wrong with old
>   report.

Comment: Is there any other info you see in the error? Do you have a grouping on a field which is available in both your datasets?

Comment: nope, the report is pretty straight forward. No grouping at all.

Comment: Do you see any additional detail in the error?

Comment: nope, that's all i get in the inner exception.

Comment: In such cases, I go and check the report XML to see if correct dataset information is defined in the report. If that doesn't help, you can remove 2nd dataset and add that again, maybe with a different name